How to transfer shape keys from blender 3.6+ to version 2.79b?
Object has equal count of vertices. When i copy (ctrl + c, ctrl + v) from 3.6 to 2.79 - error. When i append this object from blender 3.6, then object loses it shape keys. Maybe some addon? Help pls, need to work
